# Insert data into an varray of refs

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the follow structures for my oracle database 11g R2:

```
CREATE TYPE tPessoa AS OBJECT (nome VARCHAR(20), sobrenome VARCHAR(20), idade INTEGER, nacionalidade VARCHAR(20)) NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE tTecnico UNDER tPessoa (nTitulos INTEGER);
CREATE TYPE tJogador UNDER tPessoa (posicao VARCHAR(10), numero INTEGER);
CREATE TYPE tListaJogadores IS VARRAY(23) OF REF tJogador;
CREATE TYPE tSelecao AS OBJECT (pais VARCHAR(20), continente VARCHAR(20), tecnico REF tTecnico, jogadores tListaJogadores);

CREATE TABLE jogadores OF tJogador;
CREATE TABLE tecnicos OF tTecnico;
CREATE TABLE selecoes OF tSelecao;
```

I'm trying to perform an `INSERT` to the table `selecoes` but i dont realize how i can mount a list of ref tListaJogadores with an select statement. Here is what i'm trying by now:

```
INSERT INTO selecoes VALUES ('Brasil', 'America do Sul', (SELECT REF(e) FROM tecnicos e WHERE e.nacionalidade = 'Brasil'), ?????)
```

I need the solution for what i need to put on that ???? to make my query works right. The problem is only on this `????`, because the subquery on the talbe `tecnicos` are working great.

I would appreciate a solution that could solve the problem using subquery and some function that create a list of `REF's`. Here is a solution that works **ONLY** if are just **1 register** of `jogadores` with the given `nacionalidade`:

```
INSERT INTO selecoes VALUES ('Brasil', 'America do Sul', (SELECT REF(e) FROM tecnicos e WHERE e.nacionalidade = 'Brasil'), tListaJogadores((SELECT REF(j) FROM jogadores j WHERE j.nacionalidade = 'Brasil')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this suit your needs ?

```
INSERT INTO selecoes (pais, continente, tecnico, jogadores)
VALUES ('Brasil', 'America do Sul',
    (SELECT REF(e) FROM tecnicos e WHERE e.nacionalidade = 'Brasil'),
    (SELECT CAST(COLLECT(REF(j)) AS tListaJogadores) FROM jogadores j WHERE j.nacionalidade = 'Brasil')
);
```